AWS Error Message: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials
I am getting following Error Message on the newly created free tier AWS account from India using region Mumbai (ap-south-1).
AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials
I am getting the error message on the AWS UI (screenshot attached when I try to list out the Security Groups under EC2 service and AWS CLI calls as well.
debadityabhar@Debadityas-MacBook-Pro ~ % aws ec2 describe-instances

An error occurred (AuthFailure) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials

I have gone through some troubleshooting guides. Those are referring to some access token version issue (Version 1 or 2). But the region Mumbai what I have selected should be default region to
I have gone through the following steps in the Re:Post link: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/iam-validate-access-credentials
But I am not able to resolve the issue.
Please let me know if you have any solution on this.

I am using Mac OS. I just set my time automatically syncing my time zone as IST (choose as per you timezone) and the issue is resolved.

On your Mac, choose Apple menu  > System Settings, click General  in
the sidebar, then click Date & Time on the right. (You may need to
scroll down.)
Turn on “Set time and date automatically”, click Set, then enter a
network time server for your region.
Turn on “Set time zone automatically using your current location”.

